# can i globally grant access to views in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I see that I can grant select on  all tables

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to reader;
```

But I want to say that user reader can only read via views. Seems like I cannot do

```
grant select on all views in schema public to system;
```

So I have to issue a grant on each view in turn?

Comment: tx thats the dup. I dont like the new 'that solved my problem' button tho - it didnt solve my problem , just told me that I cannot do it :-)

Comment: Well... That is an answer... :(

Comment: You can put the views in a separate schema and use `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...` with that schema. That will work for views as well. Separating the views in a different schema might be a good idea anyway if they have special permissions - you can also grant permissions on the schema level.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - good idea, ty